# Multi-datacenter Ansible load balancer template

Tags: nginx, ansible

I am migrating the management of an existing multi-datacenter setup to Ansible, but I am not sure what is the best way to model it, as I am new to it.

I have three data centers D1, D2 and D3. In each, the same configuration is repeated identically:

- An **nginx load balancer** (lb.D[n]) bound to a public IP
- Two **application servers** (as[1-2].D[n]) that receive traffic solely from the local load balancer
- A slave (read only) **DB server** (db.D[n]) from which both the app servers read.

The hosts file I made so far looks something like this:

```
# DC1 -----------
[dc_1_webservers]
10.43.0.10

[dc_1_appservers]
10.43.0.20
10.43.0.21

[dc_1_dbservers]
10.43.0.30

[dc_1:children]
dc_1_webservers
dc_1_appservers
dc_1_dbservers

# DC2 -----------
[dc_2_webservers]
10.43.10.10

[dc_2_appservers]
10.43.10.20
10.43.10.21

[dc_2_dbservers]
10.43.10.30

[dc_2:children]
dc_2_webservers
dc_2_appservers
dc_2_dbservers

# DC3 -----------
[dc_3_webservers]
10.43.20.10

[dc_3_appservers]
10.43.20.20
10.43.20.21

[dc_3_dbservers]
10.43.20.30

[dc_3:children]
dc_3_webservers
dc_3_appservers
dc_3_dbservers

[webservers:children]
dc_1_webservers
dc_2_webservers
dc_3_webservers

[appservers:children]
dc_1_appservers
dc_2_appservers
dc_3_appservers
```

I have purposefully left only IP addresses in here because I would like to understand how a pure Ansible solution would work, instead of resorting to DNS.

The problem is populating correctly nginx's reverse proxy upstream, so that **only the app servers local to every DC are added** when the nginx role is run and the config file template is copied onto the load balancer machine. In particular, is it possible to do something like this?

```
# file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/loadbalancer.conf in lb.D[n] (i.e. lb.D2)
 upstream backend  {
 # Iterate over the app servers in the current data center (i.e. D2)
 {% for host in [datacenters][current_datacenter][appservers] %}
     # Add each local app server IP to the load balancing pool 
     # (i.e. 10.43.10.20 and 10.43.10.21 for DC2)
     server {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }};
 {% endfor %}
 }
```

For one thing I am not sure the hosts file makes entirely sense (should I instead be adding variables to the individual entries? In the current configuration I cannot do something like [dc][3][appservers], even though I am not sure that's where the solution lies.)

Thank you very much!

EDIT 1:

The playbook's structure is as follows:

```
main.yml
hosts
vars.yml
servers/
    webservers.yml
    appservers.yml
roles/
   base/
     files/
       ssh/
       newrelic/
     tasks/
       main.yml
     handlers/
       main.yml
   webserver/
     files/
       ssl_certs/
     templates/
       nginx/
          loadbalancer.j2
     tasks/
       main.yml
     handlers/
       main.yml
   appserver/
     files/
       pip/
         requirements.txt
     templates/
       supervisor/
          gunicorn.j2
     tasks/
        main.yml
     handlers/
        main.yml
```

The main.yml entry point is only two lines:

```
---
- include: servers/webservers.yml
- include: servers/appservers.yml
```

webservers.yml gathers facts about appservers (I figured that'd be necessary to achieve my goal, even though I am not entirely sure how yet), and then first invokes a base role that just installs some shared SSH keys, NewRelic bindings and other stuff that's common to every machine in our cloud, then invokes the actual webserver role.

```
---
- name: Gather data about appservers
  hosts:  appservers
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - debug: Gather Facts

- name: Configure all frontend web servers
  hosts: webservers
  sudo: yes
  roles:
    - { role: base }
    - { role: webserver }
```

Said "webserver" role installs nginx, copies the SSL certificates and then finally copies over the jinja2 nginx config template.

```
 - name: Install nginx configuration file.
    template: src=files/loadbalancer.j2 dest=/etc/nginx/sites-available/{{ project_name }} backup=yes
```

Comment: Your on the right track, however one shouldn't rely on the host file for variables. That's what your roles host_var/main.yml is for and the use of register for your templates in the playbook file. Check out https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/jinja2-better-ansible-playbooks-templates/ for more. I'll put up an in depth answer in the morning.

Comment: Also forgot to ask, how are you structuring the playbook ?

Comment: Thank you! I read the blog post you linked: is the `hostvars` variable the key to all this?

Answer (score 3):

You can utilize [magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) `group_names` and `groups` to look up groups defined in your inventory:

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  vars:
    dcs: [dc_1, dc_2, dc_3]
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: |
        upstream backend {
        {%- for dc in dcs %}
        {%-   if dc in group_names %}
        {%-     for host in groups[dc+'_appservers'] %}
        server {{host}};
        {%-     endfor %}
        {%-   endif %}
        {%- endfor %}
        }
```

This playbook will give you the following output.

```
TASK: [debug ]     **************************************************************** 
ok: [10.43.0.10] => {
    "msg": "upstream backend { server 10.43.0.20; server 10.43.0.21;}"
}
ok: [10.43.10.10] => {
    "msg": "upstream backend { server 10.43.10.20; server 10.43.10.21;}"
}
ok: [10.43.20.10] => {
    "msg": "upstream backend { server 10.43.20.20; server 10.43.20.21;}"
}
```

Change `server {{host}};` as you need to.